# Check if an array object contains any element of another array in JavaScript and then print according

Tags: javascript

I have an array which contains the word 'Sam'.

```
selectedItem = ['sam']
```

I then have an array of objects

```
   persons = [
  {name: 'sam', pin: u393842},
  {name: 'fred', pin: u82832}
]
```

I want to return the object in the array with the same name and selectedItem which is matching.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) (and get a badge). Your question lacks any attempt at solving this problem on your own. The idea is for you to try to get something to work and then come here with specific problems you are unable to resolve. Taking the tour and reading about [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) in the help center will provide all the information you need.

Answer (score -1):

You can do something like this:

```js
const selectedItem = ['sam'];

const persons = [
  {name: 'sam', id: u393842},
  {name: 'fred', id: u82832}
];

const selectedPersons = persons.filter(function(person) {
  return selectedItem.includes(person.name);
});

console.log(selectedPersons);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
const selectedItem = ['sam'];

const persons = [
  {name: 'sam', id: 'u393842'},
  {name: 'fred', id: 'u82832'}
];

console.log( persons.find(item => item.name == selectedItem[0] );
```